# How to capture XML response data and throw it to a variable

Tags: php, xml, curl

Below is the code I am working with. I understand 95% of it.

1. I am using cURLs to setup my headers and make a post (`httpRequest` function).
2. I then have a function (`requestTemplate`) that makes a POST to a URL that returns an XML response.
3. The next function (`prefillTemplate`)'s purpose is to collect a certain variable from the XML response (`for exp $xml->title;`) and POST it to another URL.

The problem I have is, how do I collect that variable from the XML response and throw it to the `prefillTemplate` function?

```
function httpRequest($url, $headers, $method, $body = NULL) {
if (!$method) {
  $method = "GET";
};

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // Append 'api-token' to Headers
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers, "api-token: $this-  >secure_token")); // Set the headers.

if ($body) {
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        // Append 'api-token' to Headers
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers, "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8", "api-token: $this->secure_token"));   
}

$data = curl_exec($curl);
if ($this->debug) {
  echo "In httpRequest: Recieved DATA\n===========\n" . $data .  "\n===========\n";
}
curl_close($curl);
return $data; 
}


public function requestTemplate(){


$url = $this->secure_base_url . "blahblah/prepackage.xml";
//echo "Getting documents...\n";
$header = Array();
$response = $this->httpRequest($url, $header, "POST");
return $response;


}

function prefillTemplate($data){
    $url = $this->secure_base_url . "blahblah/templates.xml";
    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><template><guid>".$data."</guid></template>";
    echo $xml;
    $header = Array();
    $response = $this->httpRequest($url, $header, "POST", $xml);
    return $response;
  }
```

Comment: Try reading the PHP XML-Parser docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I've never worked with XML because JSON is easier to handle with PHP, so you need to read it yourself.

Comment: I have an API where I retrieve an XML response.  I use `simplexml_load_string` which allows me to treat the response like an object to access a variable/parameter.  ie: `$response = simplexml_load_string([curl_function()],null,LIBXML_NOCDATA); $response->Body->RESULT->SUCCESS"`

Comment: Thank you RagingCelt for your helpful response.  I'm not sure i understand what your doing with the  curl_function()],null,LIBXML_NOCDATA.  I am familiar with simplexml_load_string() but since there is not document.xml im not sure how to use it.  My code editor also seems to think that is invalid.

Comment: Just to clarify, yes i am posting to an XML url but the response returns data in xml format.  Not another xml url :(

Comment: I have edited your question a bit, added some more formatting. You may want to clean the code a bit (removing some of the newlines), or where possible split the code samples in separate sections, for easier reading.

Comment: The code gives errors when run. Please minimize the example and make it working. It's not clear from your question what exactly prevents you from calling the function with the parameter.

Comment: It gives errors because I've excluded the url path.  If you required this php in another php file and called the requestTemplate() it works fine.

Comment: This does not add any clarity to your question.

Comment: the code really doesn't matter at this point.  I have a function that makes a post to a Url.  As the response, I get xml data back.  There is a certain part of that data I would like to throw to another function.  My question is how do you throw that data to a variable when there's no .xml extension?  I realize there is the simplexml_load function but that requires an .xml extension.  I'm am just confused as to how I can use this data.

Comment: Fyi I cannot post the rest of the code becuase I am working with an api for the company I work for and there are security tokens that are being validated as well to make these posts.  I don't want to comprimise anything I'm doing to the public.